# Unwanted login popup when I access my website

Tags: wordpress, divi

So I got a login popup when I try to access my website. I may have done a mistake configuring my WP, but I don't know what could have been wrong here. Additionally, I'm using Divi as visual page builder.

[image: Login popup]

I would like to remove it since everyone gets it when they try to access the website.

I'm using the latest version of WordPress, which is 5.7.2

Does any of you know how to remove this popup ?

Answer (score 1):

Our customer had the same problem and it turned out that the popup was inserted via hosting provider because there was a maintenance on the page before which wasn't switched off. Maybe you could to ask your hoster if there is anything active.

Comment: Thank you, they solved my problem, thanks a lot mate.

Comment: Happy to hear that! :)